# Presta valve letting all the air out when I screw it back in

Tags: presta

I'm getting frustrated with my bike's Presta valve.

I spent 20 minutes before the air would move into the tube, all undone by screwing the end of the valve back in which temporarily releases air. I reckon it was 1.5 seconds of air release getting the end of the valve screwed back in.

Any tips on how I can avoid losing air?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13439/how-to-inflate-a-tire-with-a-presta-valve?r=SearchResults

Comment: I think you’re not operating the tiny valve nut correctly. You need to unscrew it to allow air to flow through the valve. You then need to close it again afterwards. Otherwise, the valve cap will press on the valve and let all the air out.

Comment: Try to turn the acorn nut without pushing it in or out.  It doesn't require any real pressure - its more of a locknut than anything.  Note the acorn nut shouldn't come off the threaded stem at all.

Comment: Note that the threaded stem at the center of the valve may be bent or otherwise deformed, causing the acorn nut to stick as you try to screw it in or out.

Answer (score 1):

If you press down while screwing in, air will be released. The nut on the top of the Presta valve does not need any downward force to close.

If you are not pressing down while screwing in or find a lot of force is needed to turn the nut at the top of the tube, then your valve may be damaged. At that point, it is best to get a new inner tube/valve.